# How to exclude timeout from lock wait?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timeout, locking, task

I need to set timeout for my function calls to send feedback to the ui.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {

    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {

        lock(this) {

            // do work
            Thread.Sleep(5000);                
        }
    });

    // if the lock above blocks the thread, this might be timed out

    if(task.Wait(timeout)) {
        // done
    } else {
        // timeout
    }
});
```

my initial solution was that I take the lock outside of the inner task

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {

    Monitor.Enter(obj);
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {


        // do work

        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Monitor.Exit(obj);                

    });

    // if the lock above blocks the thread, task won't start.

    if(task.Wait(timeout)) {
        // done
    } else {
        // timeout
    }
});
```

but it doesn't work.

My question is, how can I specify a timeout for my task but exclude lock wait?

Comment: Is `lock`ing on `this` a good idea, is that the standard with `Task` (perhaps `this` grabs the `Task` in context, perhaps not?)?

Comment: @GrantThomas you can assume the `obj` a instance field, it doesn't make any difference, if I have two function like this, I'm in trouble. you can not call `Monitor.Enter` in one thread and `Monitor.Exit` in another.

Comment: @decPL That's not my question. I don't know if this is the right way to specify a timeout and exclude lock wait, perhaps not?

Comment: @alrz You can't 'exclude' an arbitrary part of execution time from timeout (how do you imagine such structures could work?). Your idea to move the 'offending' part outside the code is correct (though you might want to separately address the problem of this blocking your 'main' thread).

Comment: @alrz: Why are you using a lock? What problem are you *really* trying to solve?

Comment: @StephenCleary There is a COM port which doesn't respond to more than one request at a time, so I lock on the device and then send the request (and keep other requests in queue using that lock) The problem is these operations may block the thread for an unexpected time which is undesired. That's where timeout would be useful to send feedback to the user.

Comment: @alrz: I'd recommend a stream-based solution for COM port access, and treat everything as asynchronous so no threads are blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SemaphoreSlim` to do an asynchronous wait. Also, once you do that you won't need the external `Task.Run`, but I've left it in. You can use `Task.Delay` rather than `Thread.Sleep` as the former does not block the current thread, waits asynchronously and can also be cancelled via a `CancellationToken`.

```
private SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);

// Add ability to cancel work
public async Task DoWorkAsync(Action work, CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {         
        try
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync(token);
            await Task.Run(work, token);
        }
        finally     
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }

        // use await Task.Delay rather than Thread.Sleep as it doesn't use a thread
        // and stops almost immediately when cancellation requested.
        await Task.Delay(5000, token);
    }, token);
}
```

To create a timeout scenarion create a `CancellationTokenSource` with a timeout and catch the `OperationCanceledException` to observed the timeout.

```
try
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

    await DoWorkAsync(() => /*do work*/, cts.Token);
}
catch(OperationCanceledException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Operation timed out");       
}
```

Comment: How would you implement the OP's `if (TIMEOUT)` condition in your case?

I'm fairly certain `Thread.Sleep` just simulated the `//do work` bit.

Comment: as @decPL said, there is no timeout specified in your code and how you will handle it. Beside of that, I'm using .Net 4.0, so no async/await. (I'm aware of `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` package)

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to use the timeout with the `CancellationTokenSource`. Also, Task.Run is .NET 4.5, so I assumed you were using that.

Comment: @NedStoyanov Yes, that's right. I change it to use `Factory` methods.

Comment: @NedStoyanov Does it fix alrz's problem though? My in-brain-compilation might not be up to speed, but I'm fairly certain `await semaphore.WaitAsync()` will not be excluded from the 2 second timeout.

Comment: @decPL, If you give it the `CancellationToken` nobody will wait on it after the timeout, `await semaphore.WaitAsync(token)`, updated answer.